# Docker WWWUSER e "WWWGROUP variable is not set

Tags: docker

I just created a project in WLS with Laravel using the command:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

When trying to use the command docker-compose exec app bash it returns the this error:

```
WARN[0000] The "WWWUSER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "WWWGROUP" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
service "app" is not running container #1
Looking in Docker, sail-8.2/app is running normally.
```

Also when trying to use commands using sail returns this:

```
Command 'sail' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install bsdgames
```

Answer (score 0):

You last issue is the easiest to answer because it's part of the [setup](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#configuring-a-shell-alias) for sail that you likely just missed. When you initially ran your installation, the last terminal message would have been something like:

> Thank you! We hope you build something incredible. Dive in with: cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up

As you can see, the `sail` you want is located in the vendor files that were installed when composer was run. Adding the following to your computer's config file will bridge the gap.

```
alias sail='[ -f sail ] && sh sail || sh vendor/bin/sail'
```

The issue about `service "app" is not running container #1` arises because Laravel renames the container service in the `docker-compose.yml` file. You can see the service is named `laravel.test`. If you were to run, for example:

```
docker compose exec laravel.test php artisan optimize
```

Then your container's routes and config should return as cleared. Notice, too, that `docker compose` is different from `docker-compose`, which will now throw a notice that the hypenated version is being deprecated.

However, the reason why you'll want to configure your shell alias in your computer's config file (*.zshrc* or *.bashrc*) is that you can replace the first 5 sections with `sail` to run the command on your container, as opposed to your local machine, i.e.

```
sail artisan optimize
```

This is very convenient if, for example, you need your container to run on a different version of PHP than your local machine. Using the `sail` alias, or even the full path `./vendor/bin/sail`, to run your Composer and Laravel commands will target the container's version of php, not your local machine's.

With respect to the `WWWGROUP` and `WWWUSER` I don't think you need to concern yourself with this message. Sail seems to take care of setting the webuser and group in the image.